# Canon CanoScan LiDE 200 scans with a black bar

Tags: drivers, scanner, canon, sane, xsane

Hello brave Linux community.

I have a CanoScan LiDE 200, which used to work seamlessly up to now, whenever I needed it (a couple of times per year).

Unfortunately the last time, although it is properly recognized and more-or-less working, it has a strange artifact. In the middle of the scanning area, there is a black bar only for bright colors (i.e. white or near-white).

This is not a fault of the scanner, since I tried it also once more under OSX and works perfectly.

To understand what is goung on, I have attached a linux scan as well as an osx scan to see the difference.

It might be related to this [ancient question here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/image-corruption-with-canoscan-lide-200-scanner-4175568859/), but the problem is that the scanner used to work up to recently.
Any ideas what is wrong?

Linux scan
[image: Linux Scan]

OSX scan
[image: OSX Scan]

Comment: I wondered if you were using Ubuntu 17.10;

Comment: I'm having the same problem (with a Canoscan LiDE 100). It worked great previously.

Comment: Indeed I am using Ubuntu 17.10. The problem is with the xsane library which broke some things. More info here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1731459

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments and the linked bug report, downgrading the  sane backend to version 1.0.25 worked.

I followed these instructions:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompileSaneFromSource

Here are the commands I ran:

> ```
> sudo apt-get install libusb-dev build-essential libsane-dev libavahi-client-dev libavahi-glib-dev
> git clone git://anonscm.debian.org/collab-maint/sane-backends.git
> cd sane-backends/
> git checkout tags/upstream/1.0.25
> ./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var  --
> make
> sudo make install
> # reboot
> ```