# How would you downgrade the sane backend from 1.0.27 to version 1.0.25 in Ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: 18.04

Update:  A solution has not been provided.  I have given examples of why.  Maybe I am doing something wrong, but I am not an Ubuntu expert, that is why I am here for help.  It is no help when repositories keep moving and the experts expect all users to be experts.  Are there any experts here that are truly willing to actually help?

The instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1003753/897841)  seem to be outdated and do not indicate if 1.0.27 needs to be removed first.

The only reason I want to downgrade is to get my scanner working under 18.04LTS.  My understanding is that 1.0.27 is hosed up for genesys_gl847 scanners (including my Lide 100)  and the only viable solution is to down grade sane backend back to version 1.0.25

There does not seem to be any urgency to fix the bug as it has been there since the release of Ubuntu 17.04 with none of the known patches being applied.  I have seen many comments on this forum fixing the issue on 17 and 18 releases, most of them involve downgrading the package.  Unfortunately, the step by step solutions are all out dated as the repositories have moved and the threads have closed.  I came here hoping to get assistance to fix the issue which is possible and apparently a little over my head.  Yes, going to 16 is a work around, but not a solution.  And why the Ubuntu 18.04LTS developers decided to go with an experimental package (libsane1_1.0.27-1~experimental3ubuntu2_amd64) vice a known stable package is beyond  my comprehension.  I came to this forum in search for assistance with a solution which does exist, just a little beyond my capability with Ubuntu.

@user535733 Your suggestion did not work, but maybe I did it wrong.  There are several packages, the process failed on the first one I tried.  See below:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i libsane_1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package libsane:amd64.
dpkg: regarding libsane_1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb containing libsane:amd64:
 libsane1:i386 conflicts with libsane (<< 1.0.27-1~)
  libsane:amd64 (version 1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu1) is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing archive libsane_1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing libsane:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libsane_1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
$
```

Comment: Have you (or somebody) filed a bug report on the regression?

Comment: I believe bugs have been filed ever since Ubuntu 17 was released, however, no permanent resolution has been presented.  Many work arounds including downgrading have been offered.  Unfortunately it seems repositories have been moved around since work arounds have been presented only making it more difficult to implement.

Comment: For example this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1731459).

Comment: You can find sane backend version 1.0.25 [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu1/+build/7638464).

Comment: @Hobbyist Do I need to remove 1.0.27 first?  My first attempt to do so wanted to remove my Mate interface as well.  Can I just install the backend version 1.0.25 deb files?

Comment: @user535733 Your suggestion did not work, but maybe I did it wrong.  There are several packages, the process failed on the first one I tried.  See below:

Comment: Read your output. It means you need to downgrade libsane, too. You will probably need to downgrade several dependencies. DOWNGRADING IS POSSIBLE, BUT NOT SUPPORTED. "not supported" means apt won't calculate downgrades for you. You are expected to have the skills to trace those dependencies and install them manually. Honestly, if 18.04 is incompatible with your hardware, why not simply reinstall 16.04 until the bug is fixed?

Comment: What you're trying to do is a complex and indeed expert-level feature *as it might break other things.*  if [this duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360687/need-to-downgrade-a-package-with-many-dependents) does not help, downgrade the OS to 16.04: that's still supported till [April 2021](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

Comment: I understand.  This is a forum where experts help experts. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: There is a thread over at ubuntu-mate.community that walks you through it.  Very helpful community.  And the solution was not too complex and did not break anything.